# Getting file names without extensions

Tags: c#, .net

When getting file names in a certain folder:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(currentDirName);
FileInfo[] smFiles = di.GetFiles("*.txt");
foreach (FileInfo fi in smFiles)
{
    builder.Append(fi.Name);
    builder.Append(", ");
    ...
}
```

`fi.Name` gives me a file name with its extension: `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, `file3.txt`.

How can I get the file names without the extensions? (`file1`, `file2`, `file3`)

Answer (score 595, accepted):

You can use [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx):

```
foreach (FileInfo fi in smFiles)
{
    builder.Append(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name));
    builder.Append(", ");
}
```

Although I am surprised there isn't a way to get this directly from the `FileInfo` (or at least I can't see it).

Comment: And to get the extension (to add later for example) use: Path.GetExtension(fileName);

Comment: @Juzzz That's handy if you're working with a bare string, but if you already have a FileInfo object, there's no need to bother with Path. FileInfo already provides the "Extension" property for the purpose.

Comment: I got the error " 'builder' does not exist in the current context ". I added 'system.Text' but still got same error. What is the reason?

Comment: @ffttyy `builder` will be an instance of [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) in the OP's code. It's just an example use of GetFileNameWithoutExtension - you'll likely do better writing your own code that calls it.

Comment: One gotcha to note here is that if your file contains a double extension, `GetFileNameWithoutExtension` only removes the **end** extension.

For example, the filename `example.es6.js` will become `example.es6`

Answer (score 54):

Use [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx).

Comment: Note that the Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension is not best way as it checks for **invalid path chars** and try to extract the DirectorySeparatorChar, AltDirectorySeparatorChar or VolumeSeparatorChar in a **loop** which seems not necessary for file names (not full path's)!

Answer (score 24):

This solution also prevents the addition of a trailing comma.

```
var filenames = String.Join(
                    ", ",
                    Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\", "*.txt")
                       .Select(filename => 
                           Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename)));
```

I dislike the DirectoryInfo, FileInfo for this scenario.

DirectoryInfo and FileInfo collect more data about the folder and the files than is needed so they take more time and memory than necessary.

Comment: +1. I also prefer `Directory.GetFiles` over `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` anyday, if all I want is file names.

Comment: I like this because String.Join, LINQ, no StringBuilder.

Comment: If you take a look at the source code. FileInfo's constructor is very light weight. And all the information you see is done through properties. They are only gathered when you call them

Comment: @fjch1997 - The constructor does call Path.GetFileName and checks permissions. So that seems a bit redundant.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd FileIOPermission does not check permission against the ACL. instead it's some kind of mechanism in .NET to check permission for partially trusted code. So, it shouldn't make any actual IO call. How much it impacts performance? i can't say without testing. But i assume it's not that great

Comment: Also to simplify you don't need a lamda expression. Just do this `Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\", "*.txt").Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension)`

Answer (score 21):

```
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
```

This returns the file name only without the extension type. You can also change it so you get both name and the type of file

```
 Path.GetFileName(FileName);
```

source:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, the best answer is always the shortest answer.

Comment: But in this case it's just a copy of the accepted answer, 5 years later...

Comment: This is incorrect.  'Path.GetFileName(FileName);' "Returns the file name and extension of a file path represented by a read-only character span." I used the source that is stated above. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 12):

Use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`. Path is in System.IO namespace.

Answer (score 10):

`FileInfo` knows its own extension, so you could just remove it

```
fileInfo.Name.Replace(fileInfo.Extension, "");
fileInfo.FullName.Replace(fileInfo.Extension, "");
```

or if you're paranoid that it might appear in the middle, or want to microoptimize:

```
file.Name.Substring(0, file.Name.Length - file.Extension.Length)
```

Answer (score 7):

As an additional answer (or to compound on the existing answers) you could write an extension method to accomplish this for you within the DirectoryInfo class. Here is a sample that I wrote fairly quickly that could be embellished to provide directory names or other criteria for modification, etc:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DocumentDistributor.Library
{
    public static class myExtensions
    {
        public static string[] GetFileNamesWithoutFileExtensions(this DirectoryInfo di)
        {
            FileInfo[] fi = di.GetFiles();
            List<string> returnValue = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < fi.Length; i++)
            {
                returnValue.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi[i].FullName)); 
            }

            return returnValue.ToArray<string>();
         }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I also think this method could probably be simplified or awesome-ified if it used LINQ to achieve the construction of the array, but I don't have the experience in LINQ to do it quickly enough for a sample of this kind.

**Edit 2 (almost 4 years later):** Here is the LINQ-ified method I would use:

```
public static class myExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetFileNamesWithoutExtensions(this DirectoryInfo di)
    {
        return di.GetFiles()
            .Select(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x.FullName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

if file name contains directory and you need to not lose directory:

```
fileName.Remove(fileName.LastIndexOf("."))
```

Answer (score 3):

try this,

```
string FileNameAndExtension =  "bılah bılah.pdf";
string FileName = FileNameAndExtension.Split('.')[0];
```

Comment: Attention! Not working with filenames, that have an additional point...

Comment: yep, in this case, needs to be split by the last dot only

Answer (score 2):

It seems messy to use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` in the case you already have a `FileInfo` object.

So you might take advantage of the fact `FileInfo.Extension` is part of `FileInfo.Name` to do a simple string operation, and just remove the end of the string:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(currentDirName);
FileInfo[] smFiles = di.GetFiles("*.txt");
foreach (FileInfo fi in smFiles)
{
    var name = fileInfo.Name.Remove(fileInfo.Name.Length - fileInfo.Extension.Length);
    builder.Append(name);
    builder.Append(", ");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(currentDirName);
FileInfo[] smFiles = di.GetFiles("*.txt");
string fileNames = String.Join(", ", smFiles.Select<FileInfo, string>(fi => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.FullName)));
```

This way you don't use `StringBuilder` but `String.Join()`. Also please remark that `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` needs a full path (`fi.FullName`), not `fi.Name` as I saw in one of the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my code to get a picture to load into a PictureBox and Display a Picture name in to a TextBox without Extension.

```
private void browse_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog Open = new OpenFileDialog();
        Open.Filter = "image files|*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.icon;.*;";
        if (Open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            imageLocation = Open.FileName.ToString();
            string picTureName = null;
            picTureName = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetFileName(imageLocation), null);

            pictureBox_Gift.ImageLocation = imageLocation;
            GiftName_txt.Text = picTureName.ToString();
            Savebtn.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an extension method on FileInfo:

```cs
public static partial class Extensions
{
    public static string NameWithoutExtension(this FileInfo fi) => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name);
}
```

Answering the original question:

```cs
new DirectoryInfo(dirPath).EnumerateFiles().Select(file => file.NameWithoutExtension());
```

Say you want to get all files with a certain name:

```cs
new DirectoryInfo(dirPath).EnumerateFiles().Where(file => file.NameWithoutExtension() == fileName).FullName;
```

Answer (score -6):

```
using System;

using System.IO;

public class GetwithoutExtension
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        //D:Dir dhould exists in ur system
        DirectoryInfo dir1 = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:Dir");
        FileInfo [] files = dir1.GetFiles("*xls", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (FileInfo f in files)
        {
            string filename = f.Name.ToString();
            filename= filename.Replace(".xls", "");
            Console.WriteLine(filename);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

    }

}
```

Comment: You don't seem to be aware that there is already a Framework class that does this for you.

Comment: Also, if someone named their files "Current.XLSFiles.xls" this is going to cause REAL problems.

Comment: @TomPadilla why would this cause problems?

Comment: Because this method would present "Current.files"as the file name. Because every instance of ".xls" would be replaced with"", including ones in the middle of the name.