# How to get file name without extension in Silverlight with C#?

Tags: c#, silverlight, file

I found this answer for C#

[C# getting file names without extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804990/c-getting-file-names-without-extensions)

which uses Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name), 
but it doesn't work for Silverlight.  Intellisense doesn't recognize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=VS.95%29.aspx), `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` is supported in Silverlight 3 and 4. Make sure you have imported [`System.IO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) or used:

```
... = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name);
```

Comment: I can be so lame sometimes.  I SWEAR it didn't work before. I'll mark this as answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: @Brad Boyce: If you hover over the unknown class, a small rectangle should appear below it. Click that, an you can automatically import the reference needed.

Comment: Thanks Evan, I actually had the using in there - not sure what was going on.  But I do appreciate the help.