# getting file name from file path C#

Tags: c#, string, substring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get file name from a path string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921105/get-file-name-from-a-path-string-in-c-sharp)

using : **c# asp.net vs10**

suppose, filepath = **"C:\Sys\Axa_Excel\Axa123.xlsx"**. filepath is a string variable. file can be from whatever location. but the file will be always xls/xlsx/csv. How i have to get the file name only from the filepath which is just a string?

Comment: What have you tried? HInt: Look at the static methods of the FIle, Path and Directory classes- all what you Need is there, so you obviously did not try "learning C#".

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 5):

Use [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) method.

```
string result = Path.GetFileName(@"C:\Sys\Axa_Excel\Axa123.xlsx");
```

> How i have to get the file **name only from the filepath** which is
>   just a string?

Use [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx)

```
string result = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(@"C:\Sys\Axa_Excel\Axa123.xlsx");
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of multiple questions like:

- [C# getting file names without extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804990/c-sharp-getting-file-names-without-extensions)
- [Get file name from a path string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921105/get-file-name-from-a-path-string-in-c-sharp)

However, to get the filename incl. extension, use the static method:

`Path.GetFileName`

Documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx).

To get the filename without extension, use the static method:

`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`

Documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx)  static methods.

You need `using System.IO` to do that as well.

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(@'C:\Sys\Axa_Excel\Axa123.xlsx');
string filenamewithoutextension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(@'C:\Sys\Axa_Excel\Axa123.xlsx');
```