# .NET Framework 4.0 System.IO reference missing Path Class

Tags: .net-4.0, reference, .net

I've been reading some answers on stack overflow specifically.. [Get file name from a path string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804990/getting-file-names-without-extensions). My problem is that after I've added `using System.IO;` above the `namespace`. Then attempted to call the method `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullPath);`, I can't because the [`Path Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) has not been included within my `System.IO` reference.

[image: System.IO.Path]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/nghnswsp.xsh.png))</sub>

Even though I'm using `.NET framework 4.0` with `VisualStudio 2010`.

[image: FM Target]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/viiuyqdv.b3q.png))</sub>

Could the `using System.Windows.Shapes;` reference cause issues with the `System.IO` reference? why can't I use the `Path Class` (even though MSDN states that .NET Framework 4.0 is compatible)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.IO.Path` is not a valid `using` directive. All you need to do is remove it!

`using System.IO;` is adequate enough, then `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` validates fine:

[image]

The `Path` is a class and `System.IO` is the namespace.