# C# how to get .pdf file names only from folder without extension?

Tags: c#

I got following code to get .pdf file names from temp folder but how do remove extension from this? It seems like test.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("*.pdf") doesn't work. Help please.

```
            DirectoryInfo test = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp"); 
            FileInfo[] Files = test.GetFiles("*.pdf"); 

            comboBox1.DataSource = Files;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Comment: `System.IO.PathGetFileNameWithoutExtendion(test)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting file names without extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804990/getting-file-names-without-extensions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var fileNames = Files.Select(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.Name)).ToList();
combobox1.DataSource = fileNames;
```

Answer (score 1):

`GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` is a method of `System.IO.Path`:

```
string[] Files = test.GetFiles("*.pdf")
     .Select(x => x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x.FullName))
     .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Path` class is your friend:

Use `Path.Get​File​Name​Without​Extension`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension?view=netframework-4.7.2